# Show only major category in bokeh legend

Tags: python, bokeh

I'd like to have bokeh display a legend for categorical bar chart data, but control which level of category is shown in the legend.

e.g. using the bokeh sample code below, I'd like the legend to show only the years. So "2015", "2016", "2017", instead of the current "Apples, 2015" etc.

Additionally I'm trying to hide the years on display on the x axis, so it only shows the fruits.

I've searched through bokeh's documentation for a while but can't see how to do this. I suppose I need to set the legend attribute to some sort of format string when creating the vbar but I have no idea what formats are allowed. What's the proper way to do this?

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

output_file("bars.html")

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ['2015', '2016', '2017']

data = {'fruits' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

# this creates [ ("Apples", "2015"), ("Apples", "2016"), ("Apples", "2017"), ("Pears", "2015), ... ]
x = [ (fruit, year) for fruit in fruits for year in years ]
counts = sum(zip(data['2015'], data['2016'], data['2017']), ()) # like an hstack

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, counts=counts))

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*x), plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts by Year",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

palette = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]
#p.vbar(x='x', top='counts', width=0.9, source=source)
p.vbar(x='x', top='counts', width=0.9, source=source, line_color="white",
       fill_color=factor_cmap('x', palette=palette, factors=years, start=1, end=2),
       # legend='x[0]'
       legend='x',
      )


p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_right"

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the hierarchical axis labeling, then you will need to use the method decribed in the [Visual Dodge](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.12.10/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#visual-dodge) section of the [Handling Categorical Data](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.12.10/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) chapter of the User's Guide.

Unless I am mistaken, the example there is exactly what you are asking:

```
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import dodge

output_file("dodged_bars.html")

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ['2015', '2016', '2017']

data = {'fruits' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(x_range=fruits, y_range=(0, 10), plot_height=250, 
           title="Fruit Counts by Year", toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits', -0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2015', width=0.2, 
       source=source, color="#c9d9d3", legend=value("2015"))

p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits',  0.0,  range=p.x_range), top='2016', width=0.2, 
       source=source, color="#718dbf", legend=value("2016"))

p.vbar(x=dodge('fruits',  0.25, range=p.x_range), top='2017', width=0.2, 
       source=source, color="#e84d60", legend=value("2017"))

p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, and you're right this is exaclt the appearance I wanted. But I had been avoiding using the dodge method because I'd have to rearrange the data a bit, and then explicitly calculate and set the dodges. The documentation for the dodge method suggests you should use it when your input data is not in one neat table, so it seemed a bit strange to have to break my table up just to display it on the chart. I had thought there might be a way to specify the level (or start and end depth) of the x axis labels which I was missing, but there's nothing like that?

Comment: There's not currently but there are probably several reasonable improvements that could be considered. The current categorical support is a huge improvement over previous capability, but was also the result of one big push to refactor things, so there's almost certainly good ideas or use cases that were missed in that effort. I'd suggest opening a [Github Issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) re discuss new features.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for clarifying! I thought it was better to double check just in case (since the API does evolve quite a lot), but the dodge method should work fine for now. I'll try to open an issue for to discuss a feature request as well too.

Comment: You can certainly do this without using a `dodge` too, but you would need to [construct a `Legend` and `LegendItems` manually](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#manual-legends). The "legend" parameters to glyph methods are a convenience, and can only accommodate fairly simple cases. FYI bare `legend` parameter was previously deprecated, and has subsequently been removed in version 2.0, you should update code to use more explicity `legend_value` or `legend_field` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by adding another column to the `ColumnDataSource` which maps to the category level of interest. In question code, add the following to the `ColumnDataSource`:

```
legend_names = [level1 for level0, level1 in x]
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, counts=counts, legend_name=legend_names))
```

Then change the `vbar` to use that field as the legend (as opposed to the normal legend parameter):

```
p.vbar(<other arguments>, legend_field='legend_name')
```

This makes it easy to choose any level to use as the legend.

**Result:**
[image]

**Full code:**

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import Figure
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ['2015', '2016', '2017']

data = {'fruits': fruits,
        '2015': [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016': [5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017': [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

x = [(fruit, year) for fruit in fruits for year in years]
counts = sum(zip(data['2015'], data['2016'], data['2017']), ())
legend_names = [level1 for level0, level1 in x]
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, counts=counts, legend_name=legend_names))

figure = Figure(x_range=FactorRange(*x), plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts by Year",
                toolbar_location=None, tools="")

palette = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]
figure.vbar(x='x', top='counts', width=0.9, source=source, line_color="white",
            fill_color=factor_cmap('x', palette=palette, factors=years, start=1, end=2),
            legend_field='legend_name')

figure.y_range.start = 0
figure.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
figure.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
figure.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
figure.legend.location = "top_right"

show(figure)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some quick code to build the chart dynamically. Define `increment` separately, then picking up from `figure` above:

```
def incrementer(labels, base_inc=0.25):
    num_labels = len(labels)
    midpoint = num_labels / 2 if num_labels % 2 == 0 else num_labels / 2 - 0.5
    offset = base_inc * midpoint
    even_offset = base_inc / 2 if num_labels % 2 == 0 else 0

    return [i * base_inc - offset + even_offset for i in range(num_labels)]

..... 


from bokeh.palettes import Category20

palette = Category20[20]
increments = incrementer(regions, base_inc=0.125)
for i, region in enumerate(regions):
    p.vbar(
        x=dodge('x', increments[i], range=p.x_range), top=region, width=0.1, 
           source=source, color=palette[i], legend_label=region
        )
```